# cakephp hasmany relations give error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a database with some relations.
I have two tables in this example:

```
activity_ingredients   ingredient_aliases
---------------        ---------------
id                     id
ingredient_id          ingredient_id
```

I want to make a conditions into my model to connect the tables by the field "ingredient_id". I have done in this mode:

```
class ActivityIngredients extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'ActivityIngredients'; 
        public $useTable = 'activity_ingredients';

        public $hasMany = array (
        'IngredientAlias' => array (
            'className'     => 'IngredientAlias',
            'foreignKey'   => false,
            'conditions' => array('ActivityIngredients.ingredient_id = IngredientAlias.ingredient_id')
        )
        );
    }   

class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
    public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
    public $belongsTo = array(
         'ActivityIngredients' => array(
            'className'    => 'ActivityIngredients',
            'foreignKey'   => false
        )

    );  
}
```

If I write this code give me an error like this:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ActivityIngredients.ingredient_id' in 'where clause'

But if Instead of hasMany I write hasOne it doesn't return any error and is perfect. But my relation is hasMany.. why?

To retrieve data I make a query into my UserController.
User is associated with Activity with hasMany, Activity is associated with ActivityIngredients in this mode:

```
public $hasOne = array(
            'ActivityIngredients' => array(
                'className' => 'ActivityIngredients',
                'conditions' => '',
                'dependent' => true,
                'foreignKey'   => 'activity_id'
            )
```

To retrieve data I'm using this query at the moment but I think that I have to change all query now

```
$this->User->Activity->recursive = 2;
        $activity = $this->User->Activity->findAllByUser_id($id);
        $this->set('activity', $activity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should use a singular word while defining model class. It means that the model name should be `ActivityIngredient` instead of `ActivityIngredients`.

Although if **in `activity_ingredients` table if `ingredient_id` id is a foreign key that belongs to `ingredient_aliases` table. Then it should be named as `ingredient_alias_id`. Similiarly if you would do this same in `ingredient_aliases` table, i.e. the foreign key name would be `activity_ingredient_id`.** Then there will be no problem at all.

However, I am giving a solution to your problem. Kindly check and verify.

Then your code should looks like:

```
class ActivityIngredient extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'ActivityIngredient'; 
    public $useTable = 'activity_ingredients'; // if you use singular term then no need to define $useTable

    public $hasMany = array (
    'IngredientAlias' => array (
        'className'     => 'IngredientAlias',
        'foreignKey'   => false,
        'finderQuery' => 'select * from ingredient_aliases as `IngredientAlias`
                          where `IngredientAlias`.`ingredient_id` = {$__cakeID__$}'
                               )
    );
}   

class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
    public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
    public $belongsTo = array(
                      'ActivityIngredient' => array(
                                   'className'    => 'ActivityIngredient',
                                   'foreignKey'   => 'ingredient_id' 
                                                   )
                             );  
}
```

Comment: With this code doesn't retrieve data, IngredientAlias is empty doens't take the right association...

Comment: Is there any error you received, if not check whether ingredient_id has its corresponding records in activity_ingredients table or not.

Comment: No errors, but for me now the problem is in the query into my controller. Because I use this table into the controller of the user, the user is relation with Activity, Activity with ActivityIngredients and ActivityIngredients with IngredientAlias. I have done my query in this mode: but with your mode for me is not correct right?
$this->User->Activity->recursive = 2;
  $activity = $this->User->Activity->findAllByUser_id($id);
  $this->set('activity', $activity);

Comment: yeah... ok, but you did not mention it in your question. No probs. How Activity model is associated with ActivityIngredient Model? Kindly edit your question and explain the whole scenario.

Comment: I have edited my question with more information ihope that now is compleete to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

you have used

conditions' => array('ActivityIngredients.ingredient_id = IngredientAlias.ingredient_id')

it should be

conditions' => array('ActivityIngredients.ingredient_id => IngredientAlias.ingredient_id')

Use below code

```
            public $hasMany = array (
            'IngredientAlias' => array (
                'className'     => 'IngredientAlias',
                'foreignKey'   => false,
                conditions' => array('ActivityIngredients.ingredient_id => IngredientAlias.ingredient_id')
            )
            );
        }   

    class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {

        public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
        public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
        public $belongsTo = array(
             'ActivityIngredients' => array(
                'className'    => 'ActivityIngredients',
                'foreignKey'   => false
            )

        );  
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Give me an error:Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> `IngredientAlias`.`ingredient_id`' at line 1